# Python Plotly to PNG file cutting off Bar Chart text on left margin

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am using plotly to create a horizontal bar chart in Google Colab using this library:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
```

It displays correctly on the screen, but when I try to print it to a PNG file using :

```
!pip install -U kaleido
fig.write_image(symbol + ' Financial Summary.png')
```

The PNG is created, but the Bar text is being truncated. Here is an image of the output.

[image]

Here are my settings for the Return on Invested Capital Bar. How can I get it to display the full text?

https://pastebin.com/YdhVBhM6

and here is the final fig.show() section:

https://pastebin.com/tJy0Jnw9

Any ideas?

Comment: What if you change the width of the figure?

Comment: You are a genius Derek O.   I added a width and it worked beautifully.  fig.update_layout(height = 1000,
                  width = 1500,
                  font=dict(size = 16),
                  margin = {'t':0, 'b':0, 'l':40})

Comment: Please do not use pastebin for code (or other text). Include relevant code in your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a width solves the problem. Thanks to Derek O. Here is the revised code:

```
fig.update_layout(height = 1000,
                  width = 1500,
                  font=dict(size = 16),
                  margin = {'t':0, 'b':0, 'l':40})
```